# How to loop through subarray to see if value is return in string

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Here is an example of an array that is output:

```
Array ( [CART] => Array ( [ITEMS] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 269194 [variation_id] => 0 [options] => Array ( ) [quantity] => 1 [product_name] => 15 Top Hits for Easy Piano [product_code] => HL102668 [product_price] => 14.9900 [original_price] => 14.9900 [default_currency] => 1 [customer_group] => [product_fields] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 266421 [variation_id] => 0 [options] => Array ( ) [quantity] => 1 [product_name] => Whistle [product_code] => HD245839 [product_price] => 3.9900 [original_price] => 3.9900 [default_currency] => 1 [customer_group] => [product_fields] => Array ( ) ) ) [LAST_UPDATED] => 1349829499 [NUM_ITEMS] => 2 ) [JustAddedProduct] => [CHECKOUT] => Array ( ) )
```

There is an array for each unique product (in this example there are 2 unique products.) Sometimes there will be just one, sometimes there could be 20 or more unique products.

The value that is important to me is [product_code].  You can see that in the first array, there is [product_code] => HL102668.  In the second there is [product_code] => HD245839.

How can I check to see if 'HD' exists in any of the [product_code] values?  If it does, I need to return false.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access your sub array :

```
  $products  = $array['CART']['ITEMS'];
```

Loop through your sub array :

```
   foreach ($products as $product)
```

Check if HD exists in your product_code, with either simple strstr, or with regex using preg_match (if you are comfortable with it).

```
   if (strstr($product['product_code'], "HD")) {
          // Do your actions
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem I'm having with that is there is an instance with 'HD' and an instance without 'HD'.  So it is returning my actions for both instances.  Does that mean I can't use foreach?

Comment: I see... I just counted the instances ($i = 0;)  and then for those hd instances ($i++) and it works fine.  Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, if you want to see how many HD products, yes count. If you want to skip processing HD products, just put your processing code in the else statement

Comment: The php manual specifies NOT to use `strstr()` to check for the existence of a substring.  You will find this note on the page.  Use `strpos()` instead.